# get the value of Jquery progress bar

Tags: jquery, html

I wish to find the value of the progress bar so I can increment it by a percentage in every step, but no matter what I try it either say it's undefined, or the method cannot be called before the object is instantiated.

Things i've tried:

```
 alert($('progressbar:first').prop('progress-label')); 

 progressbarValue = progressbar.find( ".progress-label" ).val();
```

### HTML

```
<div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Form Process</div></div>
```

---

```
if(condition == true) {

    progressbar = $( "#progressbar" );
    progressbarValue = progressbar.find( ".ui-progressbar-value" );
    progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );


    var size = parseInt($("#fieldWrapper .step").size(),10);
    var progress = 100/size ; 

 alert($('progressbar:first').prop('progress-label')); 
  progressbar.progressbar({
      value: progress,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );

      },
      complete: function() {
        progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
      }
    });

        progressbarValue.css({
          "background": '#' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 16777215 ).toString( 16 )
        });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the progressbar widget's value method.

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar("value");
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#method-value

Note, you must have already initiated the progressbar previously to get it's value. Otherwise, the element isn't a progressbar yet.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3sbTw/

Comment: that is returning to me the value of false any idea why?

Comment: It works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/3sbTw/ try simplifying your code until you can replicate it in a fiddle.

Comment: Ah ok figured it out, had to creature an instance of the bar outside of the loop first. Thanks